# AngularJS - form wrapper directive, for validation purpose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

Consider the form:

```
<form class="form" name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': myForm.title.$invalid}">
      <label for="title">Title: </label>
      <input id="title" name="title" class="form-control" ng-model="title"
             required>

      <div ng-messages="myForm.title.$dirty && myForm.title.$error" role="alert">
        <div ng-message="required" class="alert small with-error-font">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          Title is required!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**I want to achieve the following behaviour:**

Validation error message should appear if user started typing and left the field empty (it's not pristine anymore). Otherwise, it shouldn't be visible till user clicks submit.

So I thought it could be done by using sort of 'aspect'/'interceptor' which simply checks if form is valid. If it is, then it should invoke ng-submit function. If not, then it should invoke $setDirty on each field (so that validation errors appear) and simply return.

I want to achieve it by creating ma own directive, like the following:

```
let validateAndSubmit = function (onValidationSuccessCallback) {
  return function () {
    // this is where validation logic should happen
    onValidationSuccessCallback();
  };
};

let ValidatingFormDirective = function () {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      name: '@',
      postValidationCallback: '&'
    },
    link: function (scope) {
      scope.validateAndSubmit = validateAndSubmit(scope.postValidationCallback);
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/events/common/forms/validating-form.template.html'
  }
};

export default ValidatingFormDirective;
```

and here's my directive template:

```
<form name="{{name}}" novalidate ng-submit="validateAndSubmit()" ng-transclude></form>
```

**Problem:**

Now if I change `form` to `validation-form` in my html, it seems like `myForm` is not recognized at all, because neither ngMessages block nor ng-class appears.

How can I fix it? Or maybe should I try completely different approach?

Comment: Have you taken a look at form validators in Angular? http://plnkr.co/edit/5Q4VOdnk5ZhZRe4NYOtW?p=preview

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: How does it solve my problem? Please, be more specific.

Comment: you aren't being conscious of using an isolated scope in the directive. Really can't figure out why you want to do this in the first place since angular already has validation built in

Comment: Isn't my problem related to transcluded scope problem? You're both saying such a feature exists, but I still don't know how to achieve exactly what I'm trying to do. I know I can make button inactive based on form.$valid, but I don't want to.

Comment: it's really easy to check `myForm.$valid` in controller

Comment: Of course. And then, how would you set invalid css class on inputs? What I'm going to do, is to indeed check whether (myForm.$valid) and depend on result, run callback or set $dirty flag on fields. Did you read my question carefully? Back to the question - my problem was related to transclusion scope. It seems like transclusion scope is sibling to isolated directive's scope instead of being a child one...